# Is there a way to do AJAX pagination from JSON response with a lot of products

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

first of all I got a huge JSON file of data with products returned from the server. I managed to do pagination on the "index" page using the "page" parameter passed to the URL, however, the search button is an AJAX event.

My question is is there a way to do pagination just with the JSON data given from the Server (PHP) side, essentially "cutting",e.g. 150 products to 10 a page, or do I have to change the logic of the search and print of products?

Is there a way to make a pagination based only on returned JSON data that is being added to a variable and then printed out?

JS:

```
function searchAjax()
    {
        var text = $("#name").val();
        var id = getGroupId(); // AJAX CALL FOR GETTIN A SPECIFIC GROUP that was selected.
        var html = ``;
        var page = 0;

        $.ajax({
            url: './models/ajaxSearch.php',
            method: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                text: text,
                id: id
            },
            success: function(data)
            {
                
                html += `<h2>Results: </h2>`;

                if (data.length == 0)
                {
                    html += `<h4>There are no such Products. Try Again!</h4></div>`;
                }
                else 
                {
                    
                    for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++)
                    {
                     html +=`<div>`+data[i].call+`</div>`//ADDING data to html variable e.g.
                     }

                $('#divId').html(html);
        
                btnChange(); //For editing each article.

               
            },
            error: function(error,xhr, statusText)
            {
                console.log(id);
                console.log(text);
                alert("There Was An Error "+xhr.status+" "+statusText);
                alert(error);
            }

        });
    }
```

The PHP just returns JSON data with one SELECT.

**ANSWER**
Managed to find the solution by adding an event on the pagination buttons that have page numbers on their "href" attribute and getting that attribute and forwarding it to a seperate Ajax Call in order just to refresh the  where the content was being printed.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't ammend the PHP and SQL and pass the current page to the Ajax search so you are only returning the JSON for the current page?

Comment: I can add the LIMIT option to the PHP side... You mean like saving the current page in a... say <input type='hidden'> and try changing the PHP to return 10 results?

Comment: Correct, something along those lines would work better and depening on the volume of JSON data it would speed things up as only dealing with say 10 results each time.

Comment: Will try that. Thanks mate for the nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find the solution by adding an event on the pagination buttons that have page numbers on their "href" attribute and getting that attribute and forwarding it to a seperate Ajax Call in order just to refresh the where the content was being printed.